# What is the difference between StreamExecutionEnvironment and StreamTableEnvironment in Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Well, I'm a newbie on Apache Flink and reading some source codes on the Internet.

Sometimes I saw `StreamExecutionEnvironment` but I have also seen `StreamTableEnvironment`.

I've read the official doc but I still can't figure out their difference.

Furthermore, I'm trying to code a Flink Stream Job, which receives the data from Kafka. In this case, which kind of environment should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StreamExecutionEnvironment` is used with the DataStream API. You need a `StreamTableEnvironment` if you are going to use the higher level Table or SQL APIs.

The section of the docs on [creating a TableEnvironment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/common.html#create-a-tableenvironment) covers this in more detail.

Which you should use depends on whether you want to work with lower level data streams, or a higher level relational API. Both can be used to implement a streaming job that reads from Kafka.

The documentation includes a pair of code walkthroughs introducing both APIs, which should  help you figure out which API is better suited for your use case. See [the DataStream walkthrough](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/walkthroughs/datastream_api.html) and [the Table walkthrough](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/walkthroughs/table_api.html).

To learn the DataStream API, spend a day working through the [self-paced training](https://training.ververica.com). There's also [training for Flink SQL](https://github.com/ververica/sql-training). Both are free.